# EZPDF - Documentation, Tutorial, Anything?

Tags: php, ezpublish, ezpdf

I've been handed a project that utilizes the ezpdf class to generate PDF files. Problem is, I can't seem to find any documentation on it on the net.

I've figured out most of changes that my bosses want implemented by looking into the code itself. What I couldn't figure out is how to change the background color of a table headers.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: http://pdf-php.sourceforge.net/pdf-php/readme.php ? I'm not sure if this what you are using but it does look like it might be...

Comment: I've seen that. Unfortunately, there's nothing in there that I could use to solve my problem.

Comment: How much code are we talking about? Any scope for porting it to [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/), which is well documented and well maintained?

Comment: If I could I would've ported this to FPDF right away. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be an option right now. I'll have to work with what I currently have.

Comment: I was also wondering what happened to this library as I used it back in 2002. It was a wrapper around class.pdf.php and was distributed in two files, "class.pdf.php" and "class.ezpdf.php". The version that I have is labelled version 009. It seems that this was included in php Pear (https://pear.php.net/reference/PhpDocumentor-latest/Cpdf/Cezpdf.html). I also managed to find sources for this over here: http://pdf-php.sourceforge.net/index.php/documentation.html and http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdf-php/files/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that the eZ PDF Library is deprecated as of 4.x ([doc.ez.no](http://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Reference/Libraries/ezpdf/%28language%29/eng-GB)). However if you visit [pubsvn.ez.no](http://pubsvn.ez.no/doxygen/4.0/html/classeZPDF.html) you will find some documentation generated from the code. If you are doing this all from the templates then the template pdf functions which use the eZPDF library should still work, look [here for documentation](http://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Reference/Template-PDF-functions).